# MediaPlayer(16454): Unable to to create media player

Tags: android, media-player, android-videoview

I got this error:

```
06-28 09:32:24.266: E/MediaPlayer(16454): Unable to to create media player
06-28 09:32:24.338: W/VideoView(16454): Unable to open content: /data/data/com.laroche/cache/intro.mp4
06-28 09:32:24.338: W/VideoView(16454): java.io.IOException: setDataSourceFD failed.: status=0x80000000
06-28 09:32:24.338: W/VideoView(16454):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(Native Method)
06-28 09:32:24.338: W/VideoView(16454):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:976)
06-28 09:32:24.338: W/VideoView(16454):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:955)
06-28 09:32:24.338: W/VideoView(16454):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:918)
06-28 09:32:24.338: W/VideoView(16454):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:870)
06-28 09:32:24.338: W/VideoView(16454):     at android.widget.VideoView.openVideo(VideoView.java:236)
06-28 09:32:24.338: W/VideoView(16454):     at android.widget.VideoView.access$2000(VideoView.java:52)
06-28 09:32:24.338: W/VideoView(16454):     at android.widget.VideoView$6.surfaceCreated(VideoView.java:490)
```

when using the following code :

```
String cacheDir = getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
Log.d("video path",cacheDir+"/intro.mp4");
vvIntro.setVideoPath(cacheDir+"/intro.mp4");
vvIntro.start();
```

I want to play a video stored in cache folder

Comment: See if the chmod from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7257540/1069068) helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe MediaPlayer requires MODE_WORLD_READABLE for your Intro file. Try to save it in none PRIVE  mode.

Or you forgot to add permission for READING internal storage.

Answer (score 0):

First check your file permission. And try without the .mp4 extension if there is no other file on the same name otherwise try with a .3gp file similarly without extension.